# Compare two values and mark text with color from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I Have my query like this:

```
  $results6 = $mysqli->query("
          SELECT competitor.competitor_id, competitor.c_dob, competitor.klass,
     competitor.egaclass, competitor.category, competitor.l_name,
     competitor.f_name, competitor.team, competitor.riik_id, 
            riik.lyhend, riik.pilt,
            charge.racefee, charge.party, charge.extraparty, charge.paid,
            (racefee + extraparty) AS rahakokku,
CASE WHEN egaclass = 'E' THEN 'Elite/Adults' 
     WHEN egaclass = 'J' THEN 'Juior' 
     WHEN egaclass = 'K' THEN 'Kids'ELSE 'Veterans' END AS ageclass_text
          FROM competitor
          inner join riik on competitor.riik_id = riik.riik_id
          inner join charge on competitor.competitor_id = charge.competitor_id
          order by f_name, l_name");
```

and Table code is:

```
print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>jrNr</th><th>Competitor </th><th>D.O.B.</th><th>Age</th><th>Ageclass</th><th>Dinner</th><th>Fee</th><th>Extra dinner</th><th>Sum</th><th>Paid</th><th>Country</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
while($row = $results6->fetch_array()) {
$timestamp = strtotime($row['c_dob']);
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["competitor_id"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["f_name"].'  '.$row["l_name"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["vanus"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["ageclass_text"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["party"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["racefee"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["extraparty"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["rahakokku"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["paid"].'</td>';
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['pilt']) . '" width="30" height="20"></td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["olek"].'</td>';

 print '</tr>';
```

visually looks table:
[image]

How I Can compare field "rahakokku" (Sum) with "paid", and when "paid" is same as "rahakokku" (Sum)then Status is whit green "OK" when not same then with red ..something Lets say "false"

Comment: `if($row['rahakokku'] >= $row['paid']) { //do things }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a statement like

Here, replace the print codes for your status column.

```
if ($row["rahakokku"]==$row["paid"]) {
     // display green text
     print '<td style="background-color:#128824">'.$row["olek"].'</td>';
}
else {
     // display red text
     print '<td style="background-color:#CC1212">'.$row["olek"].'</td>';
}
```

This will change the background color of the column status.